# Inserting a new line whenever a number appears in a sentence

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a long sentence which contains numbers and words.

I need to separate it by adding a new line whenever a number appears in the sentence. This can be 1, 2 or 3 digit numbers.

example

```
23 hfsiiub 2 etwehh iugi 456 etwie hewg 3 oiehoehgs
```

I need it this way

```
23 hfsiiub. 
2 etwehh iugi
456 etwie hewg
3 oiehoehgs
```

Can this be done in Microsoft excel or word?

Answer (score 2):

Place your data in cells, select the cells and run:

```
Sub GiveMeABreak()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        arr = Split(r.Text, " ")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If IsNumeric(arr(i)) Then
                arr(i) = vbCrLf & arr(i)
            End If
        Next i
        r.Value = Join(arr, " ")
        r.WrapText = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Ooh, nice subroutine name. I would have explained (or linked to an explanation of) how to use user-defined macros, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Your issue can be solved using Text To Column command:**

[image]

- Select Cell and from **Data Tab** click **Text 
  To Column**.
- Select **Fixed Width** option then hit 
  **Next**.

*You find this:*
[image]

- Double Click on separator arrows you need 
  to remove and finally click **Finish** 
  button.

*You find this:*
[image]

- You find words separated at Numbers.

[image]

- Select Separated row & **Copy** it.
- Place cell pointer at blank Cell & use **Paste 
  Special** then **Transpose.**

*You get the data in desire order:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Word, use "Find and Replace" with Wildcards to search for `[0-9]{1,3}` and replace with `^p^&`

[image]